# Window Screenshot Python Arcade Library

Tags: python, arcade

How does one take a screenshot of the current window using the Python Arcade library?

I have built a simulator using the Python Arcade library and would like to take a screenshot of the window programmatically when interesting events occur.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arcade.draw_commands.get_image(x=0, y=0, width=None, height=None)
```

Get an image from the screen. You can save the image like:

```
image = get_image()
image.save('screenshot.png', 'PNG')
```

[Source](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/api/drawing_primitives.html#arcade.get_image)